# How to force wp_enqueue_style to display CSS at the very bottom of the head tag to override all CSS rules?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am currently studying on how to create Wordpress administration templates via plug-ins, and according to the [Wordpress Wiki](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes) you can use hooks such as **admin_head**, **wp_admin_css**, and/or **login_head** to manually echo your link html tag:

```
echo "<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-content/plugins/blue-steel/login.css" />'."\n";
```

The example obviously is **A Bad Thing** because of the way the link tag is hardcoded inside php logic.

The ideal is to use **wp_enqueue_style()** to insert CSS. However, it has it's own idea of **WHEN** the CSS is inserted, and only reacts to the hooks it likes. For example, wp_enqueue style doesn't respond well inside **admin_head**. So far I can only use it inside **wp_print_styles** and **init**, but then again you can't really display the CSS after all the default CSS has loaded:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=0&amp;dir=ltr&amp;load=plugin-install,global,wp-admin&amp;ver=9e478aac7934ae559830ecb557b6511d' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='pinq-admin-css'  href='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/ardee/css/pinq-admin.css?ver=3.0.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='thickbox-css'  href='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.css?ver=20090514' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='colors-css'  href='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/css/colors-fresh.css?ver=20100610' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

I just want **pinq-admin-css** to display at the rock-bottom of the head tag (preferably just before the closing head) so that it can override all Wordpress-related CSS that has been loaded.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hey. There's an argument called `$deps` for `wp_enqueue_style`, you should give it a try. You might be able to mention that your stylesheet depends on all the rest, thus putting it below the others. Other than that, you can also go ahead with `!important`. More info on dependencies: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Comment: wp_enqueue_style('pinq-admin', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . "/css/pinq-admin.css", array('colors', 'thickbox')) did the trick. It went below thickbox-css and colors-css. Ingenious. Thanks!

Comment: You can also use this technique to ensure your queued css comes after just the site style.css by setting $deps to array('%theme_name%-style')

Answer (score 0):

I know this is ancient, but here's some actual code, cut and pasted from my site. This is in the functions.php file of my child theme:

```
 add_action('init', 'add_custom_styles', 99);
 function add_custom_styles() {
     wp_enqueue_style(
         'custom-styles',
         get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/custom.css',
         array('storefront-style', 'wc-bundle-style','storefront-child-style')
    );
 }
```

The `'custom-styles'` is simply a file titled "custom.css" in the child theme directory which contains all my custom styles I want to be loaded last.

In addition, to find the handles of the stylesheets that you want to be above your custom.css stylesheet, use the technique outlined here:

http://crunchify.com/how-to-print-all-loaded-java-scripts-and-css-stylesheets-handle-for-your-wordpress-blog/