# Wordpress: How to override all default theme CSS so your custom one is loaded the last?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a problem where I've been able to include a custom css in the  section of my wordpress theme with the following code:

```
function load_my_style_wp_enqueue_scripts()
{
wp_register_style('my_styles_css', includes_url("/css/my_styles.css"));
wp_enqueue_style('my_styles_css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','load_my_style_wp_enqueue_scripts');
```

But the order in the source code is as follows:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='my_styles_css-css'  href='http://...folderA.../my_styles.css?ver=3.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="default-css" href="http://...folderB.../default.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="user-css" href="http://...folderC.../user.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
```

I want my_styles_css to be the last file to load, overriding default and user files. I've tried to achieve this by modifying wp_enqueue_style in different ways, but without any success. I've tried:

```
wp_enqueue_style('my_styles_css', array('default','user'));
```

or

```
wp_enqueue_style('my_styles_css', false, array('default','user'), '1.0', 'all');
```

I've seen some related questions without answer or with these last 2 methods that are still failing for me.

The function above is part of a plugin that I've got enabled in my wordpress installation.

Answer (score 3):

The add_action function has a priority parameter that might help:

> $priority
>   (int) (optional) How important your function is. Alter this to make your function be called before or after other functions. The default is 10, so (for example) setting it to 5 would make it run earlier and setting it to 12 would make it run later.
>   Default: 10

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

Or you could directly link to your css in your header.php file rather than using wp_enqueue_style, and therefore place it exactly where you want.

Otherwise there seems to be an answer here: [How to force wp_enqueue_style to display CSS at the very bottom of the head tag to override all CSS rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212436/how-to-force-wp-enqueue-style-to-display-css-at-the-very-bottom-of-the-head-tag)

Comment: I read the related link and that's how I got to this problem. Not sure how he was using the 'add_action' call but with my syntax is not working.

I've tried to use that $priority with a value of 12 to make it load later:
 `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','load_my_style_wp_enqueue_scripts',12);`
 
but still loading before 'default' and 'user'.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to add a stylesheet to your theme is by way of the wp_enqueue_style() function:

```
wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );
```

With $deps you specify which stylesheets should be loaded before your custom stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

What about `add_action('wp_head','load_my_style_wp_enqueue_scripts');`?

Use `wp_head` instead of `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

Comment: I've tried with 'wp_head' and it's adding the style inside the 'body' rather than the 'head' hence it's not getting applied:  
    
 `add_action('wp_head','load_my_style_wp_enqueue_scripts');    

    <head>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" id="default-css" href="http://../default.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />  
    <link rel="stylesheet" id="user-css" href=".../user.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />  
    </head>  
  
    <body>  
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='my_styles_css-css'  href='.../my_styles.css?ver=3.1' type='text/css' media='all' />  
    </body>  `

Comment: That's strange, it should be inside 'head' according to [wp_head](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) reference

Answer (score 0):

Why not edit the theme?

You can do this from the Dashboard

`Appearance -> Editor -> header.php`

Just add your css last.

Comment: I didn't want to edit the theme (header.php) because I've got some styles that want to share with different sites and I want to make it theme independent...